# Is there a way to cancel Userform_Terminate if conditions are not met?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an Excel utility that reads/writes tag values to and from a PLC. Some of the tag values are Boolean, therefore range checking is very important. I created a Userform_Termiate() event that first calls a range checking sub, and then updates the sheet that houses the actual data for the form. My question is, is there anyway I can cancel the termination of the user form if the input is not in range? I will post what I have now, which just tells the user the input is not in range, cancels the update for the sheet, but then still closes the form.

```
Private Sub Userform_Terminate()

Call CheckNumericRange

If Check = True Then

    UpdateC1Sheet

Else

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to look at the QueryClose event instead.

Comment: You can't stop the form from terminating inside the Form_Terminate event. I would suggest you trigger your validation in some other event.

Answer (score 0):

[UserForm_Terminate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/terminate-event-visual-basic-for-applications) event occurs on closure of the userform. For example, if you close (Manually)/ unload(With procedure) the userform, the following procedure will give the message box.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
MsgBox "You closed the useform"
End Sub
```

So, if you want to keep the userform open while `UpdateC1Sheet` is running, then first confirm the public boolean variable `Check` variable is set to `True` in some other macro. .. OR .. If it is set to `True` in `CheckNumericRange` procedure, you can also add in the same procedure after it is set to `True` -:-

```
If Check = True Then
UpdateC1Sheet
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the `Terminate` event, from my understanding of your intentions, you'd be better off using the `QueryClose` event.

Straight from the MS documentation online;

### [QueryClose event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/queryclose-event):

> Occurs before a *UserForm* closes.

### [Terminate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/terminate-event-visual-basic-for-applications):

> Occurs when *all* references to an instance of an *object* are removed from memory by setting all variables that refer to the object to **Nothing** or when the last reference to the object goes out of scope.

So in layman's terms, say you click the red X close button or have some *close my userform* `CommandButton` on your form, the `QueryClose` event fires which has a `Cancel` part - allowing you to catch the close operation and decide if you want to do cancel the close event or not. If you don't cancel the close opearation in the QueryClose event, the form is unloaded from memory and thus the `Terminate` event is fired.

You could change your code to the following, to evaluate `Check` and either cancel closing the form or not.

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

Call CheckNumericRange
If Check = True Then
    UpdateC1Sheet
Else
    Cancel = 1 '1 = True
End If
End Sub
```